# How to disable or hide a button in intro.js for a specific step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, intro.js

Currently, I am facing an issue, when I try to disabling a button in a particular step ?

my code is like this

```
var intro = introJs();

intro.setOptions({
    steps: [
        {
            element: "#add_temp",
            intro: "Add your template"
        },            
        {
            element: "#addButton",
            intro: "Please click on add button ",
            position:'left',  
            hideNext: true            
      }
  ],    
})
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm looking for the same answer as you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is not possible. Why would you want to hide the next button anyway? You can, however, use `hideNext` to hide the next button on the last tip or use `showButtons` to hide all navigation buttons. Read [Intro.js docs for available options](https://introjs.com/docs/intro/options/#adding-options).

Comment: Okay i understand, but i want to know  is their any possible way to disable Next or Previous button in some specific step.My objective is to take client to different tab in same page but no need to go back or move forward in some insistence.

Answer (score 0):

The above method will not work if there is a run type of validation checking. For example, if that element is a check box or input field and until the user selects it or fill it up the next button will not be activated. In that scenario, we have to follow the below process.

.ts file

```
 this.introJS.onafterchange(() => {
  var original_onclick = $('.introjs-nextbutton').get(0).onclick;
  // == taxId field checking ===
  if (this.introJS._currentStep === 1) {
    if (this.addEntityForm.controls.taxId.value !== '') {
      $('.introjs-nextbutton').removeClass('introjs-disabled');
      $('.introjs-nextbutton').get(0).onclick = original_onclick;
    } else {
      $('.introjs-nextbutton').addClass('introjs-disabled');
      $('.introjs-nextbutton').get(0).onclick = null;
    }
  }
}


addTaxId(value: string): void {
 if (value !== '') {
  $('.introjs-nextbutton').removeClass('introjs-disabled');
  $('.introjs-nextbutton').get(0).onclick = original_onclick;
 } else {
  $('.introjs-nextbutton').addClass('introjs-disabled');
  $('.introjs-nextbutton').get(0).onclick = null;
 }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <input formControlName="taxId" type="text" class="form-border-bottom" #taxId (keyup)="addTaxId(taxId.value)">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const onBeforeChange = (x) => {
    if (x === 'on step you want to hide') var y = enter code heredocument.getElementsByClassName('introjs-nextbutton')[0];
    if (y) y.style.display = 'none';
}
```

where onBeforeChange is a predefined function in Steps in intro.js-react.